# How can add URL to dropdown items for a profile page

Tags: profile

I have been trying to edit the a profile page of my civicrm. I have gone the way of modifying relevant template and php file but no headway yet.

So, how can I add URL/Link (e.g. "Organisation") to the dropdown items on this profile from the UI or template?

[image: Profile page]

---

Donation Options (the three options to unhide in the same page once clicked)

[image]

Comment: It's very difficult to answer this question without more information.  Could you explain more about what you're trying to do?  Do you want the link to appear in the "Supporter" drop-down? Is the link supposed to be clickable by the user? How would that work - wouldn't that mean they wouldn't complete the profile?  Could you include a screenshot of the custom field settings for your "Supporter" field, assuming that's a custom field? If not, which field is it?

Comment: Also you haven't told us what "Supporter" is? Is it a custom field? And what is the link supposed to do?

Comment: @JonG Thanks for your comments. Firstly, it is a custom field. Link: once 'Organisation' is clicked, I want additional fields to appear such as 'Organisation Name' and once 'Government' is clicked, 'Government' custom should appear with list including 'Executive'|'Legislature'|'Judiciary'.  Secondly, I want to replicate same in another profile page for payment options. I will include the screenshot of the second page. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

profiles are simply a way to build forms so only a subset of all the gazillion fields that civi have are exposed to the end user.

so the initial question is what is that supporter field you want to add? It has to be already created in civi before you can use it.

that notion of supporter doesn't exist in civi by default, so either you are using an existing field and slightly changing it's meaning, or you need to first create a custom field 'supporter' so it's exactly what you want.

if by link you mean letting the end user putting their website, there is a core field for that- website, that you can simply add to the form

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, and if you are on Drupal, then you can use Webform-CiviCRM module to make core and custom fields available to the webform. You can then use Webforms Conditional options to set is so eg if I choose Citrus I then see another set of fields for Orange, Lemon, or if I initially chose StoneFruit, then I would see options for Peach, Apricot etc.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks @petednz. I am actually on WordPress. Good explanation though.